# Cannot find wrapMintingPolicy after updating to latest release of plutus-apps

Tags: plutus, minting, mintingpolicy

I've just checked out the latest release of the plutus-apps repository and ensured to copy the respective cabal.project dependencies (including their commit hashes). But I get a weird error, I didn't receive running it with the older version.

```
src/Contract/MyPolicy.hs:44:43: error:
    • Not in scope: ‘Scripts.wrapMintingPolicy’
      Module ‘Ledger.Typed.Scripts’ does not export ‘wrapMintingPolicy’.
    • In the Template Haskell quotation
        [|| \ oref' tn'
              -> Scripts.wrapMintingPolicy $ mkMyPolicy oref' tn' ||]
      In the typed splice:
        $$(PlutusTx.compile
             [|| \ oref' tn'
                   -> Scripts.wrapMintingPolicy $ mkMyPolicy oref' tn' ||])
   |
44 |     $$(PlutusTx.compile [|| \oref' tn' -> Scripts.wrapMintingPolicy $ mkMyPolicy oref' tn' ||])
```

Usually, the `Ledger.Typed.Scripts` modules exported the `wrapMintingPolicy` function.
[Source 1](https://playground.plutus.iohkdev.io/doc/haddock/plutus-ledger/html/src/Ledger.Typed.Scripts.MonetaryPolicies.html#wrapMintingPolicy)

**cabal.project**:

```
source-repository-package
  type: git
  location: https://github.com/input-output-hk/plutus-apps.git
  tag: v1.0.0-alpha1

...

source-repository-package
  type: git
  location: https://github.com/input-output-hk/plutus
  tag: a56c96598b4b25c9e28215214d25189331087244
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try to replace `Scripts.wrapMintingPolicy` with `Scripts.mkUntypedMintingPolicy`

```
...

import Plutus.Script.Utils.V1.Typed.Scripts qualified as Scripts

...
$$(PlutusTx.compile
             [|| \ oref' tn'
                   -> Scripts.mkUntypedMintingPolicy $ mkMyPolicy oref' tn' ||])
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I really appreciate it! It looks like all of these wrappers are being removed with the new Plutus version.
Just found this commit:
https://github.com/input-output-hk/plutus-apps/commit/91ee6f5b9d2cb6c620803ee367a2d1a145d63b48